# Bigquery parallel processing based on column value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table `student_record` with two columns

1. studentId : int
2. result: array of tuple (int, int):  (subjectId, score)

I need to do analysis on each subject separately and there are over 100 subjects.
Right now I just loop through all the subject `s` and save the output of the following query to a dataframe and do the analysis

```
SELECT studentId, res.subject, res.score 
FROM student_record, UNNEST(result) res 
WHERE res.subject = s
```

This query could take a long time to finish (100 + subjects, 100 million students) and it needs to be run for each subject.

I am wondering if there is a better way to perform such a task with parallel processing in BQ (e.g. run a single query and save results into local files indexed by subject?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is very straightforward and should be pretty quick. If you are writing millions of rows to a dataframe, that is probably your bottleneck.
I would consider one of the following approaches:

1. Try to do your analysis in BQ rather than in a script.  This depends on the analysis you are doing, but BQ has basic [statistical functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/statistical_aggregate_functions).

```
with data as (
      select studentId, res.subject, res.score 
      from student_record, unnest(result) res 
)
select
    subject,
    count(distinct studentID) as student_count,
    avg(score) as avg_score,
    max(score) as max_score,
    min(score) as min_score,
    variance(score) as var_score,
    stddev(score) as std_dev_score,
    --- etc etc
from data
group by subject
```

2. If you do need to write every studentID and score to a dataframe for each subject, I suggest materializing your query to a table and cluster by subject.  Your subsequent queries (when filtered by subject) will be more efficient (and cheaper!).

```
create table dataset.student_record_clustered_by_subject
(  
  studentId string, -- or int depending on makeup of your column
  subject string, 
  score int -- or decimal if you have decimal places
)
cluster by subject
as (
      select studentId, res.subject, res.score 
      from student_record, unnest(result) res 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The analysis I need to do is quite involved so I cannot directly apply some of the functions to compute the stats. I am trying #2 which seems to help a lot!